# is setState is shallow copy or deep copy in react

Tags: reactjs

When we set the state does reference address get changed, i.e, does react do shallow copy or deep copy in `setState`?

```
this.setState({count:1})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How does `setState()` work?**

Whenever you pass an object to `setState()`(you can also pass functions here), React take this object and merges it into the `state` object.

**How does merging of two objects work?**

Merging of two objects works like this: If both objects have a property with the same name, then the second object property overwrites the first. Let's see an example,

```js
let obj1 = { // Consider this as state
    name: 'Ajay',
    music: ['Shape of you','Closer']
}

let obj2 = { // Consider this as the object you pass to setState()
    music: 'Cheap Thrills'
}

let obj3 = {...obj1, ...obj2} // Consider this as the new state

console.log(obj3)
```

---

Output

```js
{ name: 'Ajay', music: 'Cheap Thrills' }
```

---

**Note** that it's only a shallow merge. Hence, `setState()` doesn't perform a deep copy. It merely performs a shallow merge.

Comment: How could it make a deep copy?